# Encrypting password within Web API or Database?

Tags: .net, database, api, encryption, password-protection

From client application, I am POSTING a password in plain text using HTTPS to the web API. The API is responsible to save the password in the database (using EF).

My understanding is posting a password in plain text as long as it is done under HTTPS with SSL certificate is safe. My question is should I hash and encrypt the password in Web API and then store in database or can I pass it plainly and have a stored procedure or trigger encrypt the password before saving? If in Web API, any example/tutorial/useful link demonstrating this is highly appreciated.

P.S. I own all layers of the solution and so I can make the change wherever is appropriate.

Comment: Yes, absolutely store the **hashed** password and never the actual/clear text password. As far as in which tier/layer to do that in is up to you. IMO I like to use the service layer (asp.net) because it is the most flexible as far as programming is concerned. Trying to generate secure hashes in a database could be cumbersome.

Comment: @igor do you know of a good example online?

Comment: As of 2018, you should be hashing using argon2, bcrypt or scrypt.

Comment: You can google for c# implementations of [pbkdf2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt), or [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) (or better yet existing NuGet packages of these implementations).